# How to I create a labelled scatter plot?

Tags: plot, julia, scatter-plot, gadfly

I would like to draw a labelled scatterplot, like shown below,
in Gadfly.

[image: Like this example]
(Source: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/images/renda.png)

How can I do this?

The scatter plot is easy:

```
using Gadfly
X = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4]
Y = [4, 4, 7, 7, 9, 1, 8]
Labels = ["bill", "susan", "megan", "eric", "fran", "alex", "fred"]

plot(x=X, y=Y)
```

On Option is to use colours, but that isn't so great, cos the legend becomes huge (particularly in less trivial examples than this).

```
plot(x=X,y=Y, color=Labels)
```

[image: colors]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While @Oxinabox's answer works, the Gadfly way would be to use [`Geom.label`](http://gadflyjl.org/geom_label.html), e.g.

```
using Gadfly
X = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4]
Y = [4, 4, 7, 7, 9, 1, 8]
Labels = ["bill", "susan", "megan", "eric", "fran", "alex", "fred"]

plot(x=X, y=Y, label=Labels, Geom.point, Geom.label)
```

[image: Gadfly Plot]

There are a lot of benefits to this, including smart label placement to avoid label overlap, or you can pick from some easy-to-use rules like `:centered` or `below`. Plus it'll pick up font/font size from the theme.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [Compose](https://github.com/dcjones/Compose.jl) annotations.

[The Gadfly documentation on that is here.](http://gadflyjl.org/guide_annotation.html) You might have missed its true power from the simple example shown.

```
Using Compose
plot(x=X, y=Y, Guide.annotation(compose(context(), text(X, Y, Labels))))
```

[image: With labels]